# How do I expand a pandas data frame such that each row becomes all previous rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My goal is to be able to cumulatively add rows for each group in the data frame as I have done manually below but without using a for loop or df.apply() (So basically one operation).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]]),
                   columns=['group', 'a', 'b'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 1, 1], [2, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 1, 1], [3, 1, 1], [3, 2, 2]]),
                   columns=['group', 'a', 'b'])

df1 = df1.set_index('group').sort_index()
df2 = df2.set_index('group').sort_index()

print(df1)

       a  b
group      
1      1  1
2      2  2
3      3  3

print(df2)

       a  b
group      
1      1  1
2      1  1
2      2  2
3      1  1
3      1  1
3      2  2
```

Comment: What's the logic, exactly?

Comment: Are you asking what this is for?

Comment: How you end up with df2 is not clear. Is the last group supposed to be 1, 1; 2, 2; 3, 3?

Comment: Cumulatively, each group is appended with the previous groups. So nothing is done to the 1st group, then the 1st group is appended onto the 2nd group, then the 1st and 2nd groups are appended onto the 3rd group.

Comment: Then why isn't the third group 1/2/3 after expansion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can use:

```py
tmp = pd.DataFrame(1, columns=df1.columns, index=df1.index.repeat(range(len(df1))))
df2 = pd.concat([tmp, df1]).sort_index()
print(df2)

# Output
       a  b
group      
1      1  1
2      1  1
2      2  2
3      1  1
3      1  1
3      3  3
```

One line:

```py
df2 = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(1, columns=df1.columns, index=df1.index.repeat(range(len(df1)))), df1]).sort_index()
```

Comment: If this is the fastest way to do it then yes it does. I imagine it is since its a built in operation. Thank you. I need to apply this operation to a very large data frame so I am trying to avoid for loops or df.apply() which I hear can be slow.

Comment: @Nikolas If this answer is correct, then your sample expected output in your question is wrong, because two columns in your question end with **2**, while the two columns here end with **3**.